# Site template requires feature enabled error

Tags: 2010, error, site-template

I'm trying to take a site template I downloaded from another site collection and make it a sub site on another collection. I keep getting this error when trying to create the site from the template.

> The site template requires that the feature
>   {4bcccd62-dcaf-46dc-e38277ef33f4} be activated in the site collection.

I've tried turing on publishing services and some other things but have had no luck, I still get the error. That guid is the Assets Library Feature, I have a site assets folder on the site and the site collection itself.

Comment: what type of site tempalte being used for the site collection where template created.

Comment: check this one.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12356/the-site-template-requires-that-the-feature-guid-be-installed-in-the-farm-or-s

Comment: I did see that, I'm thinking that is my issue @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Comment: you have two options, try to deactivate that feature on the source site collection then create the template...2nd option is try to activate that user using poweshell as you already have the feature ID. after enabling then try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to activate the feature using the feature id in powershell for my site collection.

Thank you @WaqasSarwarMCSE

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/1bc3885f-c27f-42aa-b4f7-b6f44f08a602/sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure-failed-to-enable-feature) on the MSDN forums indicates that is a site collection scoped feature, which wouldn't be valid with what you are trying to do. You are trying to take a template from a site collection and make it a subsite which is why it is complaining.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean root web when you say site collection?

Comment: I have a sub site on a site collection. I save it as a template and download it to my computer. I then save it as a template on another site collection and try to create a sub site with it. I get this error